# jQuery validate - if an option is selected make the next option not required?

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I'm a complete noob, new to everything basically following tutorials to understand, I'm using the jQuery Form Plugin

I'm trying to make a form where "contact type" is chosen, and if "phone" option is chosen, then it makes the "time of contact" required, but if "email" is chosen then it makes the "time of contact" not required.

*The form html.***

```
<form id="askquestion" action="questionprocess.php" method="post">

                <td><label for="response type">Method of contact:</label></td>
                <td><select name="response_type"> 
                    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please select --</option>

                    <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
                    <option value="Email">Email</option>
                    </select></td>
                    </tr>

                    <td><label for="response time">Best time to contact:</label></td>
                <td><select name="contact_time"> 
                    <option value="" selected="selected">-- Please select --</option>
                    <option value="morning_noon">Morning to Noon</option>
                    <option value="noon_afternoon">Noon to afternoon</option>
                    <option value="evenings">Evenings</option>
                    </select></td>
                    </tr>


        </form>
```

jQuery rules:

```
$(function() {
    // Validate the contact form
  $('#askquestion').validate({
    // Specify what the errors should look like
    // when they are dynamically added to the form
    errorElement: "label",
    wrapper: "td",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore( element.parent().parent() );
        error.wrap("<tr class='error'></tr>");
        $("<td></td>").insertBefore(error);
    },

    // Add requirements to each of the fields
    rules: {

        response_type: {
            required:true,
        },


        contact_time: {
            required:true,
        },
```

**Update.** This is how the validate form ends.

```
// Use Ajax to send everything to form processing file
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#send").attr("value", "Sending...");
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                $(form).slideUp("fast");
                $("#response").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("fast");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rules: {
    response_type: {
        required: true,
        contact_time: {
            depends: function () {
                return $('#askquestion select[name="response_type"]').val() === 'Phone';
            }
        }
    },
```

It's in the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#code

Comment: Thanks for that, this has a steep learning curve, I think I needed a closing bracket, as it wouldn't validate any.
`code`rules: {
    response_type: {
        required: true,
    },
        contact_time: {
            depends: function () {
                return $('#askquestion select[name="response_type"]').val() === 'Phone';`code`


It ignores the required value for both response_type and contact_time.

Comment: @FindingMozart, yes, of course, apologies, the object needs to be closed properly.  I've edited my answer to add the missing bracket. Thx.

Comment: Appreciate the help you've given, like I said, complete noob, I do understand the code you supplied and trying to learn, hope you don't mind me further asking for help. Right now, the form doesn't require validation for contact_time if email in response_type is selected -- which is great, what I wanted.

However, choosing phone in the form seems to breaks the form and (in a local non-server environment) throws up the php page.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm going to guess it knows phone is required, but doesn't know what to do when it's selected?

Comment: In a server environment, it just sends the form to email, at the moment the php is catching the basic input fields as not validated.

Comment: Worked it out! I feel quite acomplished now (although a bit stupid). Because my html form I had used 

<option value="" selected="selected">-- Please select --</option>

The error wasn't triggering. So putting in a "input type="hidden" triggers it!

Comment: `depends: function (e) {
    return $(e).closest('form').find('select[name="response_type"]').val() === 'Phone' ;
}`

If you want to use multple form or dynamical form where ID might don't used.